# no value for argument self in unbound method call

Tags: python, class

Thanks for reading this. I've spent the past 48 hours trying to get this code to work. First of all I must disclose that this is for a college assignment. I'm not looking for any assistance or comment on how I might 'gain' in the assignment, I just need to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have googled the issue and I've read through tutorials on classes and I do feel like I understand them and have got the examples to work. This one issue is stumping me.

So, I have a class which will read a database as follows:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

class DAOdv:
    #dbConn=mysql.connector.connect()
    def __init__(self):
        # import the config file
        config=pd.read_csv('./files/config.ini')
        dbName=config.iloc[int(config[config['item']=='databaseName'].index[0])]['setting']
        uname=config.iloc[int(config[config['item']=='username'].index[0])]['setting']
        hst=config.iloc[int(config[config['item']=='host'].index[0])]['setting']
        prt=config.iloc[int(config[config['item']=='port'].index[0])]['setting']

        # create the connection
        self.dbConn=mysql.connector.connect(
            host=hst,
            database=dbName,
            port=prt,
            username=uname,
            password='' # no password on Server as yet
        )

    def allClients(self):
        cursor=self.dbConn.cursor()
        sSQL = 'SELECT * FROM clients'
        cursor.execute(sSQL)
        results=cursor.fetchall()
        return results

daoDV=DAOdv()
```

and the 'server' code which is:

```
from flask import Flask
from daoDV import DAOdv

app=Flask(__name__, static_url_path='',static_folder='')

# curl "http://127.0.0.1:5000/clients"
@app.route('/clients')
def getAll():
    results=DAOdv.allClients()
    return results
```

In python, the second last line above, DAOdv is underlined in red and hovering over it produces the message "no value for argument self in unbound method call"

What am I doing wrong? I'm assuming the error is in the class?? but I can't figure out what.

Many thanks for your help with this.

Seamus

Comment: `DAOdv` is a class. You want to call `allClients()` on an instance of that class. Try `DAOdv().allClients()`.

Comment: ^^ That or import `daoDV` that you created in the first file since that is an instance

Comment: Unrelated, but this DAOdv class never closes the database connection. This is very bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DAOdv` is the class itself, not the instantiated object which you create at the end with: `daoDV=DAOdv()`.

Change your server code to:

```
from daoDV import daoDV  # note the capitalization - we're importing the object here

#(...)
results = daoDV.allClients()
```

Comment: OK, both answers worked. However, when I returned to my lecturer with the first solution he pointed to the same issue tzaman mentioned warning that I needed to be careful of running out of connections. I'm afraid, in the absence of knowledge I must got with what I feel is right. If I'm wrong in this, I would be grateful for a third party to correct me.

Comment: @Seamus yes, the other answer works too but it creates a new object every time which is generally not what you want. The whole point of instantiating a single `daoDV` object in the other module is that every server method can re-use the same object (and thus the same connection). Every time you call `DAOdv()` you run the `__init__` code again, which is slower since it has to reload the config and recreate the connection.

Answer (score 3):

Your method `allClients()` is an instance method, not a class method.
That's why you should call it like:

```
results=DAOdv().allClients()
```

Methods can be an instance or class method.
Class methods are methods which have `@classmethod` decorator.

Comment: .... so basic and so simple ..... when you know how! Thank you Zaven. Full credit in my assignment!